# How to ignore SSL certificate errors with QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt5, qwebengineview

How can I ignore and enable/disable SSL certificate errors through C++ in [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html)? I found that [QWebEnginePage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) has the virtual method [certificateError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#certificateError) but it is not accessible through QWebEngineView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution now is to derive from [QWebEnginePage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html), overwrite the method [certificateError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#certificateError) and pass an instance of the derived class to [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) with a call of [setPage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setPage). Here is an example if someone is interested.

*webpage.h*

```
#ifndef WEBPAGE_H
#define WEBPAGE_H

#include <QWebEnginePage>

class WebPage : public QWebEnginePage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WebPage(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    bool certificateError(const QWebEngineCertificateError &error) override;
};

#endif // WEBPAGE_H
```

*webpage.cpp*

```
#include "webpage.h"

WebPage::WebPage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWebEnginePage(parent)
{
}

bool WebPage::certificateError(const QWebEngineCertificateError &error)
{
    // TODO: conditional treatment
    return error.isOverridable();
}
```

Usage:

```
auto webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
auto webPage = new WebPage(this);
webView->setPage(webPage);
```

Answer (score 2):

In QT 6 this has been changed to a slot.  You can connect it and call acceptCertificate:

```
connect(this, &WebPage::certificateError, this, &WebPage::onCertificateError);
```

...

```
void WebPage::onCertificateError(QWebEngineCertificateError
    error) {
#if IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS   qWarning() << "WebPage:: ignoring certificate error: " << error.description();  
    auto mutableError = const_cast<QWebEngineCertificateError&>(error);
    mutableError.acceptCertificate();     
#endif   
    qCritical() << "WebPage:: certificate error: " << error.description();   }
```